# Left align text under an image (link) that floats right?

Tags: image, html

I have this image link:

```
<p class="alignright">
    <a target="_blank" href="...">
        <img width="230" height="158" align="right" style="margin-right: 30px;  margin-top: 20px;" src="some_source" >
    </a>
    text should go here
</p>
```

The alignright class looks like that:

```
.alignright {
    float: right;
    margin: 4px 0 1px 10px;
}
```

Now I tried several things to place text below the above image link (I tried using a < br > and image captions for example), but everything failed. The text is either too far on the left, or its not even below the image link.

Any ideas how to get the text below the image link?

Thanks!

Comment: Which Text are you talking about?

Comment: Some text, doesnt matter what ... it will be different each time, I just need to know the general way.

Comment: So you want that your text should appear below the image link , is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean that you want the text to be aligned to the **left edge** of the image link?

This means that you have to put both elements into one container and assign the float:left property to this one:

I guess that this is the "" I can see in your sample.
Did you make sure, that the width of the p-Element is the same as of the image link?

Otherwise the text would be aligned to the p-borders wherever they are on your page.

Shrink the size of the p-Element or put everything into an extra container:

```
<div style="float:right; width:#IMAGE_LINK_WIDTH#; text-align:left;">
  <a href="">IMAGE_LINK</a>
  <!-- A <br /> might be placed here -->
  Text
</div>
```

Comment: Here is a fiddle for other interested: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vYRLZ/2/). Thanks @freebird for preparing it!

Answer (score 1):

after `<p class="alignright"></p>` tag put

```
<br style="clear: both;" />
some text here
```

Text will appear under the image.

Comment: Thanks, that looks promising, only one more thing. If the text I place below is a link, its all on one line, how can I break the link when the image width is reached? You know what I mean?

Answer (score 0):

**[Live Sample](http://jsfiddle.net/vYRLZ/)**

Just add a `span` or a `div` with `clear:both` property and then align your text as you need.

**EDIT:**

If the text below the image is a `link` then just wrap the link inside a `p` tag like this

```
<p><a href="#">Your Text</a></p>
```

By doing this your `link` will appear in the next line as `p` is a `block` element.

`Block` elements force line breaks before and after the position they are placed at.

**[See Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vYRLZ/1/)**

Comment: Thanks, that looks promising, only one more thing. If the text I place below is a link, its all on one line, how can I break the link when the image width is reached? You know what I mean?

Answer (score 0):

This is html file

```
<a href="#" target="_blank"><img src=""><span id="title" >your text</span></a>
```

This is css file

```
span#title {
text-align: center;
font-weight: bold;
}

span {
background: black;
bottom: 459px;
padding: 5px;
color: white;
opacity: 0.7;
position: absolute;
left: 8px;
width: 244px;
}
```

Try in this way

Comment: Let me know whether it is helpful or not